# MySQL DELETE With a Sub-Query using Having and Count

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

Am trying to DELETE several entries using the following Query:

First i find the entries that i want to delete using this query:

```
SELECT guid FROM account GROUP BY guid,type HAVING count(type) > 1);
```

Then i add this query to the DELETE statement:

```
DELETE FROM account WHERE guid IN (SELECT guid FROM account GROUP BY guid,type HAVING count(type) > 1);
```

But i get this error:

**You can't specify target table 'account' for update in FROM clause**

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use temporary table to achieve your need as below:

1. Step1: Create temp table

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MyTemp
   SELECT guid FROM account 
   GROUP BY guid,type HAVING count(type) > 1;
   ```
2. Use the temp table in your delete statement

   ```
   DELETE FROM account 
   WHERE guid IN (SELECT guid FROM MyTemp);
   ```
3. Drop the temp table

   ```
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE MyTemp;
   ```

**EDIT:** I think a work around with **two nested tables* also works:

```
  DELETE FROM account 
    WHERE guid IN 
     (SELECT guid FROM 
       (SELECT guid FROM account 
       GROUP BY guid,type HAVING count(type) > 1) as MyTemp
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is solved,just do as following..

```
    DELETE FROM account 

      WHERE guid IN 

     (SELECT * FROM 

       (SELECT guid FROM account 

          GROUP BY guid,type 

          HAVING  count(type) > 1) AS a);
```

Comment: Thank you Abhik but you can't delete from the same table you are selecting.

Answer (score -1):

First create view

```
create view view_acct as 
SELECT guid FROM account 
GROUP BY guid,type HAVING count(type) > 1;
```

After use view

```
DELETE FROM account WHERE guid in (select * from view_acct);
```